# Python http request from url, answer in xml format

Tags: python, xml, http

i am going to work with python http requests. I need to get a request lets say from httpbin.org/get, get its content, convert it into xml format and post it back let say to httpbin.org/post. I also need to handle 10-15 requests a minute. Do i need to use grequests(async) or requests library? Code i tried:

```
import grequests

urls = ['http://www.google.com/finance','http://finance.yahoo.com/','http://www.bloomberg.com/']
def def1(response,**kwargs):
print(response.url," is available...")
def def2(response,**kwargs):
print(response.url," content is: ",response.content)
def requestAsync(urls):
responses=[]
for u in urls:
    get=grequests.get(u,hooks={'response':def1})
    post=grequests.post("http://httpbin.org/post",hooks={'response':def2},data="some data")
    responses.append(get)
    responses.append(post)
return grequests.map(responses)
print(requestAsync(urls))
```

Answer (score -1):

grequests is definitely a better way of implementing the design, it will be harder to implement though.

What is the issue you are facing with the code ?

Comment: Please put this in the comments

Comment: How can i convert response i got into xml format and post back? How can i setup timeout(60 secs) for request/response?